# Best method to get todays data through a view snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My warehouse details:

```
warehouse - XS
reading data external tables from s3 into snowflake
Refresh structure: SNS
```

I have the S3 folder structure as below

```
S3://eveningdtaa/2022-06-07/files -- contains parquet format
S3://eveningdtaa/2022-06-08/files -- contains parquet format
S3://eveningdtaa/2022-06-09/files -- contains parquet format
```

I am using external tables to read data from snowflake tables.

```
So tables- Has historical information
   views - Has daily data
```

My view defination is a below:

```
create view result_view as (
select * from table1 where date_part=(select max(date_part) from table 1)
)
```

My question our daily views are running slow and it has only 70k rows. Is there a way to rewrite my view to pick only the latest data instead of max of date? or able to run this view faster through some indexes?

Thanks,
Xi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be rewritten using `QUALIFY`:

```
create view result_view 
as 
select * 
from table1 
qualify date_part=max(date_part) over();
```

It is also worth adding partition on date: [Partitioning Parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#partitioning-parameters)

Comment: will it have any performance benefits?

Comment: @Xi12 Potentially one table scan fewer

Comment: yes I have already partitioned table through date

Comment: Thank  for the input, will try Qualify today,

Comment: when i execute it Iam getting an error

 SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 139 unexpected 'select'. syntax error line 1 at position 150 unexpected 'date_part'. syntax error line 1 at position 161 unexpected 'over'.

Comment: This is the query  that i have used
create or replace view CB_ACQUISITIONS_quality as  ( select * from "DEV"."CRUNCH"."IONS" qualify date_part=select max(date_part) over() );

Comment: @Xi12 `qualify date_part=max(date_part) over();` - the select keyword is not correct in that context